# TestRestTemplate in junit

Tags: java, spring, junit

ArticleController.java

```
    @GetMapping(path = "articles/{article-id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Article> getArticleById( @PathVariable("article-id") Long id) {
    Article article = articleService.findById(id);
    if (article != null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(article, HttpStatus.OK);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

ArticleControllerTest.java

```
public class ArticleControllerTest {

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate template;

@Test
public void testGetArticle(){
    // how to implement it
}

private HttpEntity<Object> getHttpEntity(Object body) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);
}
```

}

i searched a lot but find nothing .... how to implement getArticle using the template and this private method ??

Comment: Take a look to [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller has a dependency to service class. And your method which you want to test is using articleService.findById(id) method. By mocking your service class you can test your controller.

Here is an example of how to use MockMvc:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProductController.class)
public class ProductControllerMvcTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private ProductService productService;

@Test
public void it_should_return_product_by_id() throws Exception {
    //given
    Long productId = 1L;
    Product product = ProductBuilder.aProduct().id(productId).title("Nokia").build();
    given(productService.findById(productId)).willReturn(product);

    //when
    mockMvc.perform(get("/product/1"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("id").value(productId))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("title").value("Nokia"));
}}
```